# How can I vectorize a function that uses lagged values of its own output?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ipython, vectorization

I'm sorry for the poor phrasing of the question, but it was the best I could do.
I know exactly what I want, but not exactly how to ask for it.

Here is the logic demonstrated by an example:

Two conditions that take on the values 1 or 0 trigger a signal that also takes on the values 1 or 0. Condition A triggers the signal (If A = 1 then signal = 1, else signal = 0) no matter what. Condition B does NOT trigger the signal, but the signal stays triggered if condition B stays equal to 1
after the signal previously has been triggered by condition A.
The signal goes back to 0 only after both A and B have gone back to 0.

**1. Input:**

[image]

**2. Desired output (signal_d)** and confirmation that a for loop can solve it (signal_l):

[image]

**3. My attempt using numpy.where():**

[image]

**4. Reproducible snippet:**

```
    # Settings
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime

    # Data frame with input and desired output i column signal_d
    df = pd.DataFrame({'condition_A':list('00001100000110'),
                       'condition_B':list('01110011111000'),
                       'signal_d':list('00001111111110')})

    colnames = list(df)
    df[colnames] = df[colnames].apply(pd.to_numeric)
    datelist = pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), periods=14).tolist()
    df['dates'] = datelist
    df = df.set_index(['dates']) 

    # Solution using a for loop with nested ifs in column signal_l
    df['signal_l'] = df['condition_A'].copy(deep = True)
    i=0
    for observations in df['signal_l']:
        if df.ix[i,'condition_A'] == 1:
            df.ix[i,'signal_l'] = 1
        else:
            # Signal previously triggered by condition_A
            # AND kept "alive" by condition_B:                
            if df.ix[i - 1,'signal_l'] & df.ix[i,'condition_B'] == 1:
                 df.ix[i,'signal_l'] = 1
            else:
                df.ix[i,'signal_l'] = 0          
        i = i + 1



    # My attempt with np.where in column signal_v1
    df['Signal_v1'] = df['condition_A'].copy()
    df['Signal_v1'] = np.where(df.condition_A == 1, 1, np.where( (df.shift(1).Signal_v1 == 1) & (df.condition_B == 1), 1, 0))

    print(df)
```

This is pretty straight forward using a for loop with lagged values and nested if sentences, but I can't figure it out using vectorized functions like `numpy.where()`. And I know this would be much faster for bigger data frames.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Could you please clarify, why `signal_d` for 2017-06-13 should be 1?

Comment: The signal is triggered by condition A = 1 and signal_d should therefore be 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to vectorize this operation that will be significantly faster than a Python loop.  (At least, not if you want to stick with just Python, pandas and numpy.)

However, you can improve the performance of this operation by simplifying your code.  Your implementation uses `if` statements and a lot of DataFrame indexing.  These are relatively costly operations.

Here's a modification of your script that includes two functions: `add_signal_l(df)` and `add_lagged(df)`.  The first is your code, just wrapped up in a function.  The second uses a simpler function to achieve the same result--still a Python loop, but it uses numpy arrays and bitwise operators.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create the test DataFrame

# Data frame with input and desired output i column signal_d
df = pd.DataFrame({'condition_A':list('00001100000110'),
                   'condition_B':list('01110011111000'),
                   'signal_d':list('00001111111110')})

colnames = list(df)
df[colnames] = df[colnames].apply(pd.to_numeric)
datelist = pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), periods=14).tolist()
df['dates'] = datelist
df = df.set_index(['dates']) 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

def add_signal_l(df):
    # Solution using a for loop with nested ifs in column signal_l
    df['signal_l'] = df['condition_A'].copy(deep = True)
    i=0
    for observations in df['signal_l']:
        if df.ix[i,'condition_A'] == 1:
            df.ix[i,'signal_l'] = 1
        else:
            # Signal previously triggered by condition_A
            # AND kept "alive" by condition_B:                
            if df.ix[i - 1,'signal_l'] & df.ix[i,'condition_B'] == 1:
                 df.ix[i,'signal_l'] = 1
            else:
                df.ix[i,'signal_l'] = 0          
        i = i + 1

def compute_lagged_signal(a, b):
    x = np.empty_like(a)
    x[0] = a[0]
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        x[i] = a[i] | (x[i-1] & b[i])
    return x

def add_lagged(df):
    df['lagged'] = compute_lagged_signal(df['condition_A'].values, df['condition_B'].values)
```

Here's a comparison of the timing of the two function, run in an IPython session:

```
In [85]: df
Out[85]: 
            condition_A  condition_B  signal_d
dates                                         
2017-06-09            0            0         0
2017-06-10            0            1         0
2017-06-11            0            1         0
2017-06-12            0            1         0
2017-06-13            1            0         1
2017-06-14            1            0         1
2017-06-15            0            1         1
2017-06-16            0            1         1
2017-06-17            0            1         1
2017-06-18            0            1         1
2017-06-19            0            1         1
2017-06-20            1            0         1
2017-06-21            1            0         1
2017-06-22            0            0         0

In [86]: %timeit add_signal_l(df)
8.45 ms ± 177 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [87]: %timeit add_lagged(df)
137 µs ± 581 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

As you can see, `add_lagged(df)` is much faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is great!